# toggle react component using hide show classname

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using this npm https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

```
<ul className={classnames('hide', {'show': props.openFilter, 'hide': !props.openFilter} )}>
</ul>
```

I do`this.setState({openFilter: !this.state.openFilter})`, but the toggle won't work, it show the first time, what's the problem?

Comment: can you please elaborate the first line of code that is of <ul> . I mean what is this classnames function

Comment: @shubham https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames

Answer (score 0):

You probably are looking for this...

```
<ul className={ this.state.openFilter ? "show" : "hide" }></ul>
```

Comment: I found that it's not caused by the expression but the value of openFilter always true, here's my actual problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44586323/dynamic-variable-on-setstate-wont-work-for-toggle

Comment: hmmm, weird why doesnt it update state.. let me try and check

Comment: @AlanJenshen, Are you setting the default state value, or assuming it will default to false?

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the rest of the function I can only presume you intended to do the following instead.

```
<ul
  className={classnames({
    show: this.state.openFilter,
    hide: !this.state.openFilter
  })}
/>
```

For clarity, `classnames` accepts arguments of strings and/or objects. String arguments appear as written is their value is truthy. Whereas object arguments key are transformed into classes where their values are truthy.