# dynamic variable on setState won't work for toggle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this function

```
toggleDropdown = (name) => {
    this.setState({
        [`open${name}`]: !this.state[`${name}`]
    })
}
```

I use it on multiple different dropdown

```
<div onClick={e=> toggleDropdown('Dropdown1')}</div>
<div onClick={e=> toggleDropdown('Dropdown2')}</div>
```

Somehow `this.state.Dropdown1` or `this.state.Dropdown2` is always true when I click the divs, it won't toggle, what's the problem?

Comment: Are you sure that you inverting the same field? `[\`open${name}\`]: !this.state[\`open${name}\`]`

Comment: And beware, `setState` is asynchronous, in you case, it is better to user this.setState(prevState => ({ }))

Comment: @hmnzr yes,  
but why this work: `this.setState({openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown})` ?

Comment: because asynchronous means it doesn't guarantee any order, so in case of slow processing, or multiple `setState` within single update cycle will cause unexpected result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things,

1. When you are setting the state based on the previous one, use the `prevState` callback mechanism for `setState` since `setState` is `asynchronous`.
2. You wnat to get `this.state.Dropdown1` and still you set `openDropdown1`

Try

```
toggleDropdown = (name) => {
    this.setState((prevState) => ({
        [name]: !prevState[name]
    }))
}
```

Comment: but why this work: `this.setState({openDropdown: !this.state.openDropdown})` ??

Comment: It will work sometimes and not some other times, depends on how quickly it was processed. The beviour of above code will not be consistent, so its advised to use the callback approach for setState